# C# Regex to detect usage of Special characters

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

I want to filter out special characters in C#.
Basically i want to allow A-Z, a-z, 0-9, hyphen, underscore, (, ), commas, spaces, \, /, spaces.
Everything else is not allowed.

I have come up with the following regex ->

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-\b/(),_\s]*
```

but this doesn't seem to work fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you say "this doesnt seem to work", ***in what way*** is it not working for you?  You need to be more specific, provide some examples.

Comment: Thanks Keoki, Will keep thatin mind while asking questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter ***out*** characters that don't match those, use a `^` at the beginning of the character class:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\\/(),_\s]+
```

The `+` quantifier will match any chars not in the character class at least once.  Also, hyphens are meta characters inside character classes, so you should escape the dangling one you have, as I have done in my example.  Also, if you want to include `\` as an allowed character, you also need to escape it inside a character class, like `[\\]`.

Also, inside a character class (also known as a character *set* defined by `[ ]`), `\b` is a backspace character, not a word boundary.

Comment: ( and) are still special characters, needs to be escaped

Comment: @Adrian not inside a character class.

Comment: still, the OP wants to allow "A-Z, a-z, 0-9, hyphen, underscore, (, ), commas, spaces, \, /, spaces."

Comment: @Adrian, yeah, I know, that's exactly what my regex does, the `^` at the beginning of the character class negates the characters inside, so anything that ***doesn't*** match those chars will get matched by the regex.

Comment: if (!Regex.IsMatch()) vs if (Regex.IsMatch())
Is a matter of logic and also matters where this is being used.

Comment: Are those C# regex methods?  I provided a general, language-neutral answer for filtering out special chars with a regex...so maybe you're right.

Comment: Yes, but does nothing more than to check if a string matches a regular expression. First statement translates "if the string doesn't match then do something", the next one "if the string does match then do something". .Net has also two common places where the expressions are used, the validators (web forms, win forms) and they are used like "if the input matches the regular expression, then you can submit the form". I hope you understand now why it does matter.

Comment: So the fact is C# it doesn't influence the special characters. You've been right with () and C# doesn't change this.

Comment: @Adrian the original poster needs to give more information about what he/she wants to do.

Comment: Keoki, Thats exactly what i wanted. I'll be using this to throw out error for the end user!

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_(),\s\\/]+$
```

it's for the whole line

Comment: Thanks Adrian. The regex by Keoki worked. The above one doesnt filter any values in C#.